# reload data from select tag each ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

i have a form which i have 2 select tag. after choosing the data from the first select tag i run an ajax request to load the other data to the next select tag..

```
 $('#carousel_type').on('change', function(){
            var selected = $(this).val();
            $.ajax({
                type:'POST',
                url:'functions/get_subcase.php',
                data:{subcase:selected},
                dataType:'JSON',
                success: function(data){

                    for(i in data)

                    $('#subcarousel_type').append('<option value = '+data[i].id+'>'+data[i].carousel_title+'</option>');
                }
            });
        });
```

this is the code i use to display the return data from my ajax.. but the problem i encounter is that if i select another data.. ajax request will only load the next request and so on..

what i wanted to do is when im selecting a data from the 1st select tag will it display on the next select tag and when i select again from the first select tag the data from the second select tag will reload..

i dont have any idea what function im missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've understood your problem correctly, the issue is because you don't remove the option elements appended in the previous call when adding the next load of data. To fix this you can call `empty()` before adding the new options, like this:

```js
$('#carousel_type').on('change', function() {
  var selected = $(this).val();

  $.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: 'functions/get_subcase.php',
    data: { subcase: selected },
    dataType: 'JSON',
    success: function(data) {
      var $subcarousel = $('#subcarousel_type').empty(); // remove previously loaded options
      for (i in data)
        $subcarousel.append('<option value = ' + data[i].id + '>' + data[i].carousel_title + '</option>');
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: amazing it works... this is what im looking for.. i just cant construct my words to search for it... thank you so much..

Comment: other answers said .html(""); what is the diff with your answer btw?.

Comment: `html()` sets the content of the element whereas `empty()` removes all existing content. You can see the exact differences in the source: [`html()`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.html), [`empty()`](https://j11y.io/jquery/#v=1.11.2&fn=jQuery.fn.empty). In this case their output would be the same, although `empty()` is more semantic for your requirements

Answer (score 2):

You need to empty your dropdown before appending

```
$('#carousel_type').on('change', function(){
    var selected = $(this).val();
    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'functions/get_subcase.php',
        data:{subcase:selected},
        dataType:'JSON',
        success: function(data){
            $('#subcarousel_type').html(""); //<-------- add this line
            for(i in data){

              $('#subcarousel_type').append('<option value = '+data[i].id+'>'+data[i].carousel_title+'</option>');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is working fine but you need to empty option and append the new value you got it form ajax call.

```
$('#subcarousel_type').empty();
```

Answer (score 1):

Put  this link when function starts.

```
    $('#subcarousel_type').html('');
```

Please do this....

```
 $('#carousel_type').on('change', function(){
    $('#subcarousel_type').html('');
        var selected = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'functions/get_subcase.php',
            data:{subcase:selected},
            dataType:'JSON',
            success: function(data){

                for(i in data)

                $('#subcarousel_type').append('<option value = '+data[i].id+'>'+data[i].carousel_title+'</option>');
            }
        });
    });
```